# How to conditionally hide PXPanel inside an Acumatica screen?

Tags: acumatica

I have the following use case:

Acumatica  dropdown, which can have 2 or so values.

e.g.:

-If user selects option a, I need to show PXPanel(ID="panel1")

-If user selects option b, I need to show PXPanel(ID="panel2")

Those PXPanels are inside in one  PXFormView, so they have one  DataMember  Like this :

```
       <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="Waybills">

               <px:PXPanel ID="panel1" ..
               <px:PXPanel ID="panel2" ..

    </px:PXFormView>
```

Is it possible to conditionally  show/hide PXPanels?

As  RuslanDev said I can achieve the same effect with PXLayoutRule(GroupCaption), but in that case I can't set caption to 100%, it's equal the first column's width.

**With PXPanel :**

[image]
apsx :

```
   <px:PXPanel ID="panel3" runat="server" Caption="Buyer (Receiver)" RenderStyle="Fieldset" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataMember="" >

        <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />
        <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edCustomerID" runat="server" DataField="CustomerID" DataSourceID="ds" />

        <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />
        <px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientTaxRegistrationID" runat="server" DataField="RecipientTaxRegistrationID" Enabled="False" CommitChanges="True" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />
        <px:PXCheckBox ID="edRecipientIsForeignCitizen" runat="server" DataField="RecipientIsForeignCitizen"  AlreadyLocalized="False"  Enabled="false"/>

        <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />
        <px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientName" runat="server" DataField="RecipientName" Enabled="False" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />


        <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />
        <px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientDestinationAddress" runat="server" DataField="RecipientDestinationAddress" CommitChanges="True" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />

    </px:PXPanel>
```

**With PXLayoutRule :**

[image]

apsx :

```
   <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" StartColumn="True"  GroupCaption="Buyer (Receiver)" StartGroup="true"  ColumnSpan="3"/>

                <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server"  StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />

                <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edCustomerID" runat="server" DataField="CustomerID" DataSourceID="ds" />

                <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientTaxRegistrationID" runat="server" DataField="RecipientTaxRegistrationID" Enabled="False" CommitChanges="True" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />
                <px:PXCheckBox ID="edRecipientIsForeignCitizen" runat="server" DataField="RecipientIsForeignCitizen"  AlreadyLocalized="False"  Enabled="false"/>

                <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientName" runat="server" DataField="RecipientName" Enabled="False" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />


                <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" ColumnWidth="XM" />
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientDestinationAddress" runat="server" DataField="RecipientDestinationAddress" CommitChanges="True" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PXFormView instead of PXPanel solved all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to hide entire PXPanel from business logic, except conditionally setting **Visible** to ***true*** or ***false*** for each input control placed within a PXPanel:

```
protected virtual void ARFinCharge_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    ARFinCharge fin = e.Row as ARFinCharge;
    if (fin == null) return;

    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<ARFinCharge.fixedAmount>(cache, fin, fin.ChargingMethod == OverdueChargingMethod.FixedAmount);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<ARFinCharge.lineThreshold>(cache, fin, fin.ChargingMethod == OverdueChargingMethod.PercentWithThreshold);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<ARFinCharge.minFinChargeAmount>(cache, fin, fin.ChargingMethod == OverdueChargingMethod.PercentWithMinAmount);
}
```

For the PXLayoutRule approach, please use Aspx layout as below (the Customer selector has to span across the 3 columns underneath it):

```
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" StartGroup="true" GroupCaption="Buyer (Receiver)" />
<px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edCustomerID" runat="server" DataField="CustomerID" />
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" Merge="True" />
<px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientTaxRegistrationID" Size="M" runat="server" DataField="RecipientTaxRegistrationID" Enabled="False" CommitChanges="True" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />
<px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientName" runat="server" Size="M" DataField="RecipientName" Enabled="False" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />
<px:PXTextEdit ID="edRecipientDestinationAddress" Size="M" runat="server" DataField="RecipientDestinationAddress" CommitChanges="True" AlreadyLocalized="False" DefaultLocale="" />
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" Merge="False" />
<px:PXCheckBox ID="edRecipientIsForeignCitizen" runat="server" DataField="RecipientIsForeignCitizen"  AlreadyLocalized="False"  Enabled="false"/>
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" EndGroup="true" />
```

[image]

Comment: I do, but panel caption still remains.  I want to hide that caption too

Comment: Have you tried to use PXLayoutRule instead of PXPanel? I believe with the GroupCaption property specified PXLayoutRule should look identical to PXPanel

Comment: I did and it works, but I faced other issues. I cant set PXLayoutRule to 100% or for example colspan 3 ...

Comment: Please update your question with screenshot and Aspx layout. Without these details, it's very hard to understand what the challenge is...

Comment: I did @RuslanDev

Comment: You're very welcome :-) Glad the issue got resolved!

Comment: I have the other issue, if just CustomerID dissapear and all the rest fields remain  Caption also dissapearing : ( @RuslanDev

Comment: I tried with no success. Did you just add Merge="True" ?

Comment: I mean if CustomerID is not visible then the whole caption is hidden, while edRecipientTaxRegistrationID, edRecipientName are still visible

Comment: @user3857731, the issue is caused by 2 PXLayoutRules with StartRow set to True in the middle of your "panel". Could you please replace the entire Aspx layout with my sample above and re-test the scenario once again?